# Android Studio Update: Cannot Load Project, Intellij Fatal Error

Tags: java, intellij-idea, android-studio

I just updated my ubuntu and then the Android Studio. The instructions told me to move the SDK folder into it's own folder in order to install the new Android Studio, which I did. I was having trouble with gradle. Now I cannot even load the project I was working on.

The error message is:

Cannot load project: com.intellij.ide.plugins.PluginManager$StartupAbortedException: Fatal error initializing 'com.intellij.openapi.vcs.changes.ChangeListManager'

Does anyone know what's happening? I am using openjdk.

Answer (score 0):

I just uninstalled and reinstalled on Ubuntu, fixed it.

But I now gradle is all effed up. sigh...

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall the plugins in the bottom of the configure. Then restart the idea.

[image]